Salesforce database providers and infrastructure
I've heard from some architects (in person) that Salesforce database on classic instances runs on Oracle infrastructure, while Hyperforce runs on PostreSQL.
I tried to find some official Salesforce statements in documentations or help sites, but could not find any.
Do you know if Salesforce have confirmed these somewhere, maybe on some recorded presentation or architectural guidelines that might not be indexed by typical Google Search?

https://careers.salesforce.com/en/jobs/ is your friend

As identigral said, job listings include roles that desire PostgreSQL as well as MySQL, so it's possible that some combination of databases are spread through the application. That said, this level of detail has traditionally been held close to the chest as Intellectual Property as well as a matter of security concerns (e.g. specific versions being run, etc). I'm not sure you'll get a very satisfying or definitive answer.
